# Eloquent Query with Eager Loading

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to perform an easy query with Eloquent.

I need to get all open tournament ( tournament->type = 1 ) that are in same country than me. Tournament has no country_id, but I need to do it with

```
$tournament->owner->country_id == Auth::user()->id
```

So, In my tournament table, I have a user_id that is the owner, and in my model, I have a working relation that get $tournament->owner

Here is my try ( doesn't work )

```
openTournaments = App\Tournament::with('owner')
    ->whereHas('owner', function ($query)  {
        $query->where('id', Auth::user()->country_id);
    })
    ->where('type', config('constants.OPEN_TOURNAMENT'))
    ->get();
```

Any Idea how to fix it???

Comment: Is this a typo? `$tournament->owner->country_id == Auth::user()->id` vs `where('id', Auth::user()->country_id)` -- those seem opposites (and the country_id == user_id seems counter intuitive also).

Comment: yep, you're right.... let me fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your schema looks like, but assuming that the user has a country_id associated with it, and a tournament has an owner associated with it, you should be able to just do this:

```
openTournaments = App\Tournament::with('owner')
->whereHas('owner', function ($query)  {
    $query->where('country_id', Auth::user()->country_id);
})
->where('type', config('constants.OPEN_TOURNAMENT'))
->get();
```

Note `country_id` instead of `id`.